# Missing bytes when reading from WebClient stream

Tags: c#

Why am I missing bytes when reading from a WebClient stream as follows?

```
const int chuckDim = 80;

System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/70/3e/a9/needed-backup-lol.jpg");
//Stream stream = client.OpenRead("file:///C:/Users/Tanganello/Downloads/needed-backup-lol.jpg");

//searching file length
WebHeaderCollection whc = client.ResponseHeaders;
int totalLength = (Int32.Parse(whc["Content-Length"]));
byte[] buffer = new byte[totalLength];

//reading and writing
FileStream filestream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Tanganello\\Downloads\\clone1.jpg", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
int accumulator = 0;
while (accumulator + chuckDim < totalLength) {
    stream.Read(buffer, accumulator, chuckDim);
    filestream.Write(buffer, accumulator, chuckDim);

    accumulator += chuckDim;
}
stream.Read(buffer, accumulator, totalLength - accumulator);
filestream.Write(buffer, accumulator, totalLength - accumulator);

stream.Close();
filestream.Flush();
filestream.Close();
```

this is what I get with the first stream:
http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/830/clone1h.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are ignoring the return value of the [Stream.Read Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx):

> *count*
>
> The **maximum** number of bytes to be read from the current stream.
>
> *Return Value*
>
> The total number of bytes read into the buffer. This can be **less** than the number of bytes requested

---

You can avoid the whole business of reading and writing streams by simply using the [WebClient.DownloadFile Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(
        "http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/01/70/3e/a9/needed-backup-lol.jpg",
        "C:\\Users\\Tanganello\\Downloads\\clone1.jpg");
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use streams, you can simply use the [Stream.CopyTo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://..."))
using (var file = File.OpenWrite("C:\\..."))
{
    stream.CopyTo(file);
}
```

If you insist on really copying the bytes yourself, the correct way to do this would be as follows:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://..."))
using (var file = File.OpenWrite("C:\\..."))
{
    var buffer = new byte[512];
    int bytesReceived;
    while ((bytesReceived = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {
        file.Write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
    }
}
```